# How can i make this slider code to autoplay in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, autoplay

Hello I'm trying to get this slider to auto play in Javascript, but I can't seem to get it to work, Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

I took the slider [from here](http://codepen.io/dayneh88/pen/BjmWad):

Here is the current code:

```
$(".button-next").click(function() {
    var e = $(".feature-slide.active");
    $(e).removeClass("active"), 
    $(e).next().addClass("active"), 
    $(".feature-slide").hasClass("active") || $(".feature-slide:first").addClass("active")
});
$(".button-prev").click(function() {
    var e = $(".feature-slide.active");
    $(e).removeClass("active"), $(e).prev().addClass("active"), $(".feature-slide").hasClass("active") || $(".feature-slide:last").addClass("active")
});
```

FYI: i'm not a developer, and obviously i'm not a javascript expert, so i'm trying to get help here because you are the experts, so if you are not going to give a positive response, restrain from answering or making negative comments, thanks!

Comment: Show what you've tried already.  "Write my code for me." questions are generally regarded as bad on SO.

Comment: wow thanks for your insightful answer, it really helped me a lot!

Comment: If you want slider with auto play you can try this http://codepen.io/Creaticode/pen/xIfmw
or this one
http://codepen.io/suez/pen/ByvKXE
study this codes and use it or change your slider using what you have learned.

Comment: Thanks El.oz i actually tried to understand the second slider you suggested, but i couldn't make it work, but i will check the first one!

Comment: @AlexPlahnz Are you need controls in this slider ? i made a function to make it sliding auto but it will have a little bug if someone clicked on next/prev buttons...

Comment: @El.oz hi El, i don't think i really need the slider controls, so i can get rid of them if you managed to get it to autoplay, can i see the function you add? thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code http://codepen.io/El-Oz/pen/qZQePV

if you want to change speed of slide you can increase/decrease the `timer` in JS code.

Comment: that looks great, thank you very much for your help El.oz, i really appreciate it!